# Gnome-screensaver settings

Tags: 18.04, gdm, gnome-screensaver

Does anyone know where I can locate gnome-screensaver settings on ubuntu 18 ? (I don't mean the GUI ones) I need it to be done through terminal. What I need to do is to tell gnome-screensaver to look for XAuthority file somewhere else rather than /home/user as our /home is nfs mounted and this causes a lot of issues for users. Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1648107

Comment: Yes, but lightdm has fixed it by creating a new option for them selfs

Comment: Gnome has not and its still causing issues